# add labels to lattice barchart

Tags: r, bar-chart, lattice

I would like to place the value for each bar in barchart (lattice) at the top of each bar. However, I cannot find any option with which I can achieve this. I can only find options for the axis.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Create a custom panel function, e.g.

```
library("lattice")
p <- barchart((1:10)^2~1:10, horiz=FALSE, ylim=c(0,120),
              panel=function(...) { 
                args <- list(...)
                panel.text(args$x, args$y, args$y, pos=3, offset=1)
                panel.barchart(...)
              })
print(p)
```

[image: lattice barchart with labels]

Comment: Works nicely for a single chart but does not seem to work for multiple chart groups?

Answer (score 0):

I would have suggested using the new [directlabels package](http://directlabels.r-forge.r-project.org/), which can be used with both lattice and ggplot (and makes life very easy for these labeling problems), but unfortunately it doesn't work with barcharts.

Answer (score 0):

Since I had to do this anyway, here's a close-enough-to-figure it out code sample along the lines of what @Alex Brown suggests (scores is a 2D array of some sort, which'll get turned into a grouped vector):

```
barchart(scores, horizontal=FALSE, stack=FALSE, 
     xlab='Sample', ylab='Mean Score (max of 9)',
     auto.key=list(rectangles=TRUE, points=FALSE),
     panel=function(x, y, box.ratio, groups, errbars, ...) {
         # We need to specify groups because it's not actually the 4th 
         # parameter
         panel.barchart(x, y, box.ratio, groups=groups, ...)
         x <- as.numeric(x)
         nvals <- nlevels(groups)
         groups <- as.numeric(groups)
         box.width <- box.ratio / (1 + box.ratio)
         for(i in unique(x)) {
             ok <- x == i
             width <- box.width / nvals
             locs <- i + width * (groups[ok] - (nvals + 1)/2)
             panel.arrows(locs, y[ok] + 0.5, scores.ses[,i], ...)
         }
     } )
```

I haven't tested this, but the important bits (the parts determining the locs etc. within the panel function) do work. That's the hard part to figure out. In my case, I was actually using panel.arrows to make errorbars (the horror!). But scores.ses is meant to be an array of the same dimension as scores.

I'll try to clean this up later - but if someone else wants to, I'm happy for it!

Answer (score -1):

If you are using the `groups` parameter you will find the labels in @rcs's code all land on top of each other.  This can be fixed by extending panel.text to work like panel.barchart, which is easy enough if you know R.

I can't post the code of the fix here for licencing reasons, sorry.

Comment: What does that mean?  Are you developing proprietary (which would have to be in-house to be legal) tools based on lattice?  (Just curious.)

Comment: because a patched version of `panel.text` would a derived work.  I'm always happy to post code samples that I write completely myself.  Also I may have at any given time contracts with my employer which have a bearing on contributing to GPL.